# Publishing the bot the skype failed due to policy urls

Tags: azure, botframework

I tried o publish a sample bot the skype and I received an email that it has not been approved.

I got following email:
Dear Developer,

Your bot Trending Pics could not be approved, because it is failing one or more certification requirements listed under  https://github.com/Microsoft/skype-dev-bots/blob/master/certification/CHECKLIST.md
The link to your bot is https://join.skype.com/bot/a2c32383-81c5-44b9-9318-e86ac2ba9222.

Please address the failures and resubmit your bot for certification. 
The Skype Bot Team.

I think I have a problem with the Privacy Policy and Terms of Use documents published online and referenced by the bot. Can someone help me with how to provide a URL for these? I don't have a website yet. Just testing the Bot on the emulator. So how can I publish it to the Skype channel?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're JUST testing the bot, for thing such as channel specific functionality, you don't need a Privacy Policy and Terms of Use. Those are for if you are going to actually publish your bot for others to see.

Connect your Bot to the Skype channel on the channels list in Azure under bot management. It will open the configuration settings page. Since this is just a test bot, you can click over to the 'calling' section, and click 'disable calling'. This will enable the 'Save' button. Click save, then click the 'channels' list again. Skype will now be listed (possibly with a warning 'There was a problem synchronizing your bot to Skype.' You can ignore this for now).

Click on the actual word 'Skype' in the list, and a join.skype.com page will open in a separate tab or window. Click 'Add to Contacts', and follow the prompts. When you next open Skype, your bot will be listed in your contacts.

Again, this is ONLY for testing. No other person will be able to connect to your bot, and you won't be able to list your bot in the [Skype Bot Shop](https://www.skype.com/en/features/bots/). If you do decide to officially publish your bot, there are sites such as [TermsFeed](https://termsfeed.com/terms-service/generator/) to help with creating a Privacy Policy and Terms of Service.

Comment: Yes, Thank you. I will try your steps and get back to you.